# I have having Error in Site Health Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

**The REST API encountered an error Performance**

The REST API is one way WordPress, and other applications, communicate with the server. One example is the block editor screen, which relies on this to display, and save, your posts and pages.

**The REST API request failed due to an error.**

Error: [] cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Your site could not complete a loopback request Performance
Loopback requests are used to run scheduled events, and are also used by the built-in editors for themes and plugins to verify code stability.

The loopback request to your site failed, this means features relying on them are not currently working as expected.
Error encountered: (0) cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue with an API that I built a while ago.

My architecture is all on digital ocean and none of the sites were able to connect to my API.

So after a long research I found the problem was the DO firewall, and the sites had not outbound rules, (https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/firewalls/how-to/configure-rules/)

So I am not sure if you have it on DO, but the firewall (in the API server as inbound) or the client to the API (as outbound) can be giving you troubles and sending that error.